# Alert is not displayed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

My test checks whether the user can log in to the site.
I wrote a code to alert that works but showing parts in `catch`. 
I tried to write alert without `try` and `catch` but displays an error.

How to write alert without `try` and `catch` and alert to be displayed(test to pass).

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 5 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
```

This is my code:

```
public void getMessage() {
        //Verify that is message preview
        try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println(alert.getText());
        alert.accept();
        Assert.assertTrue(alert.getText().contains("ERROR: Invalid login credentials."));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Alert is not displayed");
        }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: My guess is that the alert is an HTML dialog and not a JS alert. When the alert pops up, right-click on it. If you get the right-click context menu and can Inspect, then it's HTML based and not an alert.

Comment: Yes, this is html.
<p class="response" style="display: block;">
<strong>ERROR</strong>
: Invalid login credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have confirmed that the dialog is not truly a JS alert dialog, you won't be able to use `Alert`. The good news is that it's HTML just like any other part of the page so you can just scrape the element that contains the error text.